# Configuring File Names for PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, configuration, phpunit

I am a new user of PHPUnit, and I am converting our existing tests (asserts) into the PHPUnit framework to provide a better test environment and code coverage.  However, I need to know how to try to get PHPUnit working with our testing code structure.

Our project directories are similar to the following: 
Application1/ 
   CREDIT_CARD.class   - Class naming convention for CREDIT_CARD  
   CREDIT_CARD.class.test   - Automated Tests for CREDIT_CARD.class  
   File.php   - Application File  
   File.php.test   - Automated tests for File.php  
   File2.php  
   File2.php.test   - Automated tests for File2.php  

Application2/  
   ANOTHER_CLASS.class  
   ANOTHER_CLASS.class.test  
   DifferentFile.php   - Application File  
   DifferentFile.php.test   - Automated tests for File.php  

lib/  
   UTIL/  
      SHARED_CLASS.class  
      SHARED_CLASS.class.test  
   VISUAL/  
      VISUAL_TOOL.class  
      VISUAL_TOOL.class.test  

I need to know how to configure the PHPUnit tests so I can run the tests in lib/UTIL/*.test (which load the class file using the setUp() method) then the lib/VC/*.test, followed (if successful) by the Application1 and Application2 tests.  I saw mention of a PHPUnit_xml file and a bootstrap file, but I can not find a reference template to see if these are what I need.  Any help would be appreciated.

I know the documentation refers to a test.php addition to the file names, but I am hoping to not have to change our structure and naming conventions as I would like to be able to run a mix of the files until they are all converted over to the PHPUnit framework.  Changing names will cause a procedure change in our company and training for the developers, which I am trying to avoid.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: So `Filename.class.test` does contain a class that extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase? Did i get that right?

Comment: Yes. class TEST_SOME_CLASS extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        if ( ! class_exists('SOME_CLASS'))
            require_once(substr(__FILE__, 0, -5));  // strip '.test' extension
    }

 public function testConstants()
 {
     $this->assertEquals(SOME_CLASS::TYPE_1, 1);
        $this->assertEquals(SOME_CLASS::TYPE_2, 2);
 }
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you have files named `Foo.class.test` instead of the PHPUnit default `FooTest.php` ?

That shouldn't be a big problem as PHPUnit allows you to configure what file suffixes are to be treated as "tests". The `Test.php` is just the default.

Have a look at the [**`xml config part of the docs regard test organisation`**](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/11.0/configuration.html#appendixes-configuration-testsuites)

What you want is:

```
 <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Our new shiny phpunit test Suite">
      <directory suffix=".test">./sourceFolder</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
```

PHPUnit will then scan through the source folder including all files that end in `.class.test` and leaving the other files as is.

Comment: As there are some non-class test files, this might need to be `suffix=".test"`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Any chance of possibly getting a sample file posted with some of these suggestions, since I do have different files, and not much experience with PHPUnit?  I am looking at the reference, and am mostly just looking for a base file to start from to trial and error and check understandings with the document.

Comment: It should also be noted that there are some files with a .fn extension, and JavaScript and other files. IE: FunctionCode.fn, JavaScript.js, Application.css, etc...

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem.  Sorry for the delay in getting back to update this, but work priorities are always moving, hence the big need for automated testing.

Comment: link updated: https://phpunit.de/manual/4.3/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.testsuites

Comment: Is this the new preferred hyperlink? https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html#appendixes-configuration-testsuites