# test class is not specified or invalid

Tags: symfony, testing, command, phpunit

I need to run a couple of tests on a console command, each of which will have a small change to the database before the test is run. I've structured this as follows:

```
class ActionRemindCommandEmail extends KernelTestCase
{
    private $mailCollector;


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getMailCollector()
    {
        return $this->mailCollector;
    }


    /**
     * @param mixed $mailCollector
     */
    public function setMailCollector($mailCollector)
    {
        $this->mailCollector = $mailCollector;
    }



    protected function setUp()
    {
        exec('mysql database < prep.sql');
    }


    public function testExecute()
    {
        exec('echo "' . str_replace('"', '\\"', $this->getPrepSql() ) . '" | mysql database');

        self::bootKernel();
        $application = new Application(self::$kernel);

        $application->add(new ActionRemindCommand());

        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->enableProfiler();
        $this->setMailCollector($client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer'));

        $command = $application->find('app:ahp:remind');
        $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
        $commandTester->execute(array(
                                    'command'  => $command->getName(),
                                    'email' => ''
                                ));
        $output = $commandTester->getDisplay();
        $this->assertions();
    }
}
```

and the first actual test looks like this

```
    class ActionRemindCommandVetNotifyWhenSavedOnlyTest extends ActionRemindCommandEmailTest
{

    protected function getPrepSql()
    {
        return "INSERT INTO `action` (farmer_id`, `group_id`, `name`, `due`, `active`, `completed`, `notify_vet_email`, `notify_farmer_email`, `notify_vet_text`, `notify_farmer_text`, `notify_tech_text`, `notify_clinic_email`, `notify_farmer_text2`, `notified_vet_email`, `notified_farmer_email`, `notified_clinic_email`, `notified_vet_text`, `notified_farmer_text`, `notified_farmer_text2`, `notified_tech_text`, `notify_vet_email_advance`, `notify_farmer_email_advance`, `notify_clinic_email_advance`, `notify_vet_text_advance`, `notify_farmer_text_advance`, `notify_farmer_text2_advance`, `notify_tech_text_advance`, `no_time`, `notes`, `pending_offline_id`) VALUES "
                . " (116, NULL, 'Action 1', '"
                    . date('Y-m-d H:i:s',mktime(12,0,0,intval(date('n')), intval(date('j'))+14,intval(date('Y'))))
                . "', 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '000', '000', '000', '000', '000', '000', '000', -1, -1, -1, 24, 24, 24, 24, 0, 'undefined', 'N1478139417184')";

    }


    public function testExecute()
    {
        parent::testExecute();
    }

    protected function assertions()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(1, $this->getMailCollector()->getMessageCount());
    }
}
```

Setting this up in phpstorm with app/phpunit.xml.dist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="bootstrap.php.cache"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <!--
    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="/path/to/your/app/" />
    </php>
    -->

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

I find that I cannot execute the test, because "test class is not specified or invalid"

[image]

I tried using scope: class, method, but I'm not sure what else could be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specified in [PHPUnit docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html):

> If you point the PHPUnit command-line test runner to a directory it will look for *Test.php files.

Meaning that by default PHPUnit considers only classes ending with `Test.php`.

### Expected test suffix can be [changed in phpunit.xml](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html).

Looks like this:

`<directory suffix=".test">./sourceFolder</directory>`

See [this good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8917540/4725998) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Where I'm confused is: I did not try running tests in a directory, just a file and file with specified method. Also, my test file did end in *Test.php, just its parent class didn't. Any idea where this might be documented?

Comment: @jdog I hear you. Just noticed that you were extending from  `ActionRemindCommandEmailTest` in `ActionRemindCommandVetNotifyWhenSavedOnlyTest`, so that might have been just a misspell. Try again without `Test` in parent's name, it should work.

Comment: doh! (doh!Doh!Doh!)

Answer (score 0):

Adding Test as a suffix to the Parent class solved the problem.